# Smart way to read array from back in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Consider two arrays `X`&`Y`. How can you assign as shown below,

```
X(1) = Y(end);
 X(2) = Y(end-1);
...
```

Length of array changes with time.

Comment: You should try posting on Stack Overflow. I don't think this is "signal processing enough" to be considered here

Comment: Try $y  = flip(x);$

Comment: `x = y(end:-1:1) ` will also help